# Integration/Substitution AP Calc Question

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $f(x)= 12-g(x)$ for $-3$ to $3$, then
>
> $$\int f(x)-g(x)dx=$$
> $(a)$ $72$
>
> $(b)$ $2 \int_{-3}^{3} g(x)dx -72$
>
> $(c)$ $72-4 \int_0^3 g(x) dx$
>
> $(d)$ $72-2 \int_{-3}^{3}  g(x) dx   $

so far,I've tried substituting in and solving for $g(x)$ and $f(x)$, but I'm not sure where the answers get the $72$. However, I got $(a)$ when I plugged in for what $g(x)$ equals but that seems too easy.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! Please include some information about what you've tried to do so far, so that you can be given relevant hints/explanation. Otherwise you may not receive an answer as you'd wish, and your post will be downvoted.

Comment: This is pretty easy use linearity of the integral and substitute for $f(x) = 12-g(x)$

Comment: Hi, I tried substituting in f(x), but I get 12-2g(x), and then I factor out a two, but I still don't understand where they get the 72 from.

Comment: is anything missing from the question? is this a definite integral? if so, what are the limits? (we can guess, but let's be sure).

Comment: Yea, I just wasn't sure how to put it into the website format. It is from -3 to 3

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Since it is a definite integral from $-3$ to $3$, we are only interested in the value of $f(x)-g(x)$ over that region.

Over that region, $$f(x)-g(x)=12-2g(x)$$

Now, use that information and integrate over that region.